# Pasar datos de gridview a un Texbox en asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

me podrian ayudar quiero pasar los datos de un GRIDVIEW A UN TEXBOX POR FAVOR.
no logro pasar los datos quisiera que me ayuden.

**MI CODIGO ACTUAL ES ESTA ME SALE ERROR**

aqui :

**GridViewRow row = DtgVerGestiones.Rows[0];**

```
 protected void DtgGestiones_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal();", true);
            if (e.CommandName == "Gestiones")
            {
                try
                {
                    DtSet = new DataSet();
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
                    con.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_BuscarSeguimiento", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("OPT", 2);
                    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("periodo", "");
                    SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("oficina", "");
                    SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("rubro", e.Item.Cells[3].Text);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);



                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    DtgVerGestiones.DataSource = dt;
                    DtgVerGestiones.Visible = true;
                    DtgVerGestiones.DataBind();

                    GridViewRow row = DtgVerGestiones.Rows[0];

                    TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Text);

                    con.Close();






                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    // DvError.Visible = true;
                    Session["13"] = Ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
```

**CODIGO QUE DEL BOTON BUSCAR**

```
protected void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DtgVerGestiones.DataSource = null;
    DtgVerGestiones.DataBind();

    DateTime d3 = DateTime.Parse(dprPeriodo.Text);
    string Periodo = d3.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_BuscarSeguimiento", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("OPT", 1);
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("periodo", Periodo);
    SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("oficina", dprAgencia.Text);
    SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("rubro", DBNull.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);



    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    DtgGestiones.DataSource = dt;
    DtgGestiones.Visible = true;


    DtgGestiones.DataBind();

    con.Close();
}
```

**ERROR :**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Es decir este imagen es lo que me genera mi datagrid.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**YO QUIERO PASARLE ESOS DATOS EN TEXBOX ASI:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: @Davlio cuando pongo para pasar los datos con este codigo :

  TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Text);

donde dice row sale ese error y no me permite pasar de datagrid a un texbox ayudame

Comment: puse la imagen del error.

Comment: GridViewRow row = DtgVerGestiones.CurrentRow; TextBox1.text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias la tengo la solucion es crear un evento al datagridview que es **RowCommand**

```
if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                try
                {


                    DtSet = new DataSet();

                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
                    con.Open();
                    DtgSolicitudes.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    GridViewRow row = DtgSolicitudes.SelectedRow;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_BuscarSeguimiento", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("OPT", 2);
                    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("periodo", "");
                    SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("oficina", "");
                    SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("rubro", row.Cells[3].Text);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);



                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                   // DtgVerGestiones.DataSource = dt;
                   // DtgVerGestiones.Visible = true;
                   // DtgVerGestiones.DataBind();

                    if (row.Cells[11].Text == "NO")
                    {
                        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox2.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox3.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");

                        //TextBox1.Enabled = false;
                        //TextBox2.Enabled = false;
                        //TextBox3.Enabled = false;


                        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Text);
                        TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Text);
                        TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Text);
                        TextBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Text);
                        TextBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[5].Text);
                        TextBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[6].Text);
                        TextBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[7].Text);
                        TextBox8.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[8].Text);
                        TextBox9.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[9].Text);

                        Image1.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[12].Text);
                        var imagen = row.FindControl("img") as Image;

                    }
                    else if (row.Cells[11].Text == "SI")
                    {
                        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox2.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox3.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox4.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox5.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox6.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox7.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox8.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                        TextBox9.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");


                        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Text);
                        TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Text);
                        TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Text);
                        TextBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Text);
                        TextBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[5].Text);
                        TextBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[6].Text);
                        TextBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[7].Text);
                        TextBox8.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[8].Text);
                        TextBox9.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[9].Text);

                        btnActualizar.Visible = false;

                    }

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal();", true);
                    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "VGestiones", "VGestiones()", true);

                    con.Close();



                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    // DvError.Visible = true;
                    Session["13"] = Ex.Message;
                }



            }
```